# Aquantia Touchpad Driver Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, drivers, touchpad

I am in need of a touchpad driver for the Dell Precision 3520 laptop. It appears that this is the only laptop with this specific touchpad according to [Ubuntu Certification](https://certification.ubuntu.com/catalog/component/input/4932/input%3ADLL07A9%3A01044E%3A120B/). Unfortunately, I am required to use Ubuntu 12.04.5 on this laptop. It appears that it us using a touchpad by Aquantia Corp, but that is all I am able to find. Basic mouse functionality doesn't even work so at this point, I don't even care about scrolling or anything like that, just basic mouse functionality. I couldn't seem to find a driver anywhere for this touchpad online.

Below is the output of my /proc/bus/input/devices.

```
I: Bus=0019 Vendor=0000 Product=0005 Version=0000
N: Name="Lid Switch"
P: Phys=PNP0C0D/button/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/device:00/PNP0C0D:00/input/input0
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event0 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=21
B: SW=1

I: Bus=0019 Vendor=0000 Product=0001 Version=0000
N: Name="Power Button"
P: Phys=PNP0C0C/button/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/device:00/PNP0C0C:00/input/input1
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=kbd event1 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=3
B: KEY=100000 0 0 0

I: Bus=0019 Vendor=0000 Product=0003 Version=0000
N: Name="Sleep Button"
P: Phys=PNP0C0E/button/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/device:00/PNP0C0E:00/input/input2
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=kbd event2 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=3
B: KEY=4000 0 0 0 0

I: Bus=0019 Vendor=0000 Product=0001 Version=0000
N: Name="Power Button"
P: Phys=LNXPWRBN/button/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXPWRBN:00/input/input3
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=kbd event3 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=3
B: KEY=100000 0 0 0

I: Bus=0011 Vendor=0001 Product=0001 Version=ab41
N: Name="AT Translated Set 2 keyboard"
P: Phys=isa0060/serio0/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input4
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=sysrq kbd event4 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=120013
B: KEY=1100f 2902002 8380307c f910f001 feffffdf ffefffff ffffffff fffffffe
B: MSC=10
B: LED=7

I: Bus=0003 Vendor=03f0 Product=094a Version=0111
N: Name="PixArt HP USB Optical Mouse"
P: Phys=usb-0000:00:14.0-1/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/input/input5
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=mouse0 event5 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=17
B: KEY=ff0000 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
B: REL=103
B: MSC=10

I: Bus=0019 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="Dell WMI hotkeys"
P: Phys=wmi/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/virtual/input/input6
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=kbd event6 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=13
B: KEY=101001b 400 0 100000 e0000 0 0 0
B: MSC=10

I: Bus=0003 Vendor=0c45 Product=6717 Version=7524
N: Name="Integrated_Webcam_HD"
P: Phys=usb-0000:00:14.0-11/button
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-11/1-11:1.0/input/input7
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=kbd event7 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=3
B: KEY=100000 0 0 0 0 0 0

I: Bus=0000 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="HDA Intel HDMI"
P: Phys=ALSA
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input9
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event8 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=21
B: SW=140

I: Bus=0000 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="HDA Intel Front Headphone"
P: Phys=ALSA
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input8
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event9 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=21
B: SW=4
```

Below is an output of lspci -v.

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 1910 (rev 07)
    Subsystem: Dell Device 07a9
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Capabilities: <access denied>

00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 1901 (rev 07) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=01, subordinate=01, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 0000e000-0000efff
    Memory behind bridge: ec000000-ed0fffff
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000c0000000-00000000d1ffffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 191b (rev 06) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Dell Device 07a9
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 11
    Memory at eb000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at 80000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    I/O ports at f000 [size=64]
    Expansion ROM at <unassigned> [disabled]
    Capabilities: <access denied>

00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device 1903 (rev 07)
    Subsystem: Dell Device 07a9
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 11
    Memory at ed340000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=32K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>

00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Device a12f (rev 31) (prog-if 30 [XHCI])
    Subsystem: Dell Device 07a9
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 140
    Memory at ed330000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd

00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device a131 (rev 31)
    Subsystem: Dell Device 07a9
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 11
    Memory at ed358000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>

00:15.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device a160 (rev 31)
    Subsystem: Dell Device 07a9
    Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 11
    Memory at ed357000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [disabled] [size=4K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>

00:15.1 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device a161 (rev 31)
    Subsystem: Dell Device 07a9
    Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 10
    Memory at ed356000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [disabled] [size=4K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>

00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Device a13a (rev 31)
    Subsystem: Dell Device 07a9
    Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 11
    Memory at ed355000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [disabled] [size=4K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>

00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Device a102 (rev 31) (prog-if 01 [AHCI 1.0])
    Subsystem: Dell Device 07a9
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 141
    Memory at ed350000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
    Memory at ed354000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
    I/O ports at f090 [size=8]
    I/O ports at f080 [size=4]
    I/O ports at f060 [size=32]
    Memory at ed353000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ahci
    Kernel modules: ahci

00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device a111 (rev f1) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=02, subordinate=02, sec-latency=0
    Memory behind bridge: ed200000-ed2fffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp

00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device a112 (rev f1) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=03, subordinate=03, sec-latency=0
    Memory behind bridge: ed100000-ed1fffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp

00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device a114 (rev f1) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=04, subordinate=3c, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 00002000-00002fff
    Memory behind bridge: d4000000-ea0fffff
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 0000000090000000-00000000b1ffffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp

00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device a154 (rev 31)
    Subsystem: Dell Device 07a9
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0

00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Device a121 (rev 31)
    Subsystem: Dell Device 07a9
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Memory at ed34c000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]

00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Device a171 (rev 31)
    Subsystem: Dell Device 07a9
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 32, IRQ 143
    Memory at ed348000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Memory at ed320000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd-hda-intel

00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Device a123 (rev 31)
    Subsystem: Dell Device 07a9
    Flags: medium devsel, IRQ 11
    Memory at ed352000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
    I/O ports at f040 [size=32]

00:1f.6 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Device 15e3 (rev 31)
    Subsystem: Dell Device 07a9
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 142
    Memory at ed300000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=128K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: e1000e
    Kernel modules: e1000e

01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 13b4 (rev a2)
    Subsystem: Dell Device 07a9
    Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 16
    Memory at ec000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at c0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    Memory at d0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=32M]
    I/O ports at e000 [size=128]
    Expansion ROM at ed000000 [disabled] [size=512K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel modules: nouveau, nvidiafb

02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Device 24fd (rev 78)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 0050
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 11
    Memory at ed200000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>

03:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device 525a (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Dell Device 07a9
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 11
    Memory at ed100000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
```

Comment: By the way, the "PixArt HP USB Optical Mouse" is the external USB mouse since the trackpad doesn't work.

Comment: Does anyone have a solution for this?